# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError > com/sun/net/ssl/internal/www/protocol/https/DelegateHttpsURLConnection

Tags: java

I am getting an error as below while running my application. The application runs fine but then one method throws this error

```
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> com/sun/net/ssl/internal/www/protocol/https/DelegateHttpsURLConnection
>        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionOldImpl.<init>(HttpsURLConnectionOldImpl.java:82)
>        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:53)
>        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:49)
>        at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:981)
>        at benefit.com.aciworldwide.commerce.gateway.plugins.e24PaymentPipe.sendMessage(e24PaymentPipe.java:562)
>        at benefit.com.aciworldwide.commerce.gateway.plugins.e24PaymentPipe.performPaymentInitialization(e24PaymentPipe.java:400)
>        at com.mobile.payment.BEOPayment.initBEOPayment(BEOPayment.java:76)
>        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
>        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
>        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
>        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
>        at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
>        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
```

Any idea why is that?

Comment: Unless you describe what kind of application and what you are doing in that app, its not possible to give solution.

Comment: Its a worklight application where we have integrated third party JARs and one of those methods internally is throwing this error.

Comment: Please provide more info about what kind of API/.jar and what exactly trying to do and when it occurs?. How anyone can blindly predict the problem when u say integrated third party jar?

Comment: check to see if the DlegateHttpsURLConnection calss exists in your external jar.  seems like its part of jsse.jar - http://jar.fyicenter.com/200_jdk_jsse.jar_jdk_1.6.0_06_java_secure_socket_extension.html

Answer (score 0):

Most probably its caused by Jar conflict.

First find the jar name in your war file which holds this class file then use [tattletale](http://tattletale.jboss.org/) for knowing which jar is conflicting.
Hope this will resolve your issue

if you are in linux try to run this command to know if same class exist in other jar

```
jar -tvf *.jar | grep -i DelegateHttpsURLConnection
```